# Is there a name for functions that have multiple minima such that all minima are equal/one minima is less than another?

Tags: maxima-minima

Is there a name for a concept like that I can search? I am completely okay if there is no name so far.

For example, $f\left(x\right)=\sin\left(x\right)$ has infinite minima, but they are all at $f\left(x\right)=-1$. On the contrary, $f\left(x\right)=\sin\left(x\right)+\sin\left(.5x\right)$ also has infinite minima, but some are at $f\left(x\right)\approx-.369$ while some are at $f\left(x\right)\approx-1.76$.

For now I have been calling them "stable" and "unstable" functions for now. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
From the comments for one of the answers, I feel like "recurrent absolute minimum" and "recurrent non-absolute minimum" are the terms I will use for now.

The problem I am working on is something with optimization, figuring out if I can use any local minimum as my absolute minimum. The thing is, its also constrained to a set range for all inputs, so while there will be multiple local minima, I wouldn't say there are infinite.

Comment: As far as I know there is no name for such property. In general, concepts tend to have names when more mathematics are built upon them. This property might be frequent in your context though. If it does, you can give it a name yourself as you did (but may be my suggestion would be to use less connoted names to not induce potential readers in error, including you in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl; dr: The terms *absolute minimum*, and *relative minimum* or *local minimum*, are commonly-used for what you're calling "stable" and "unstable" minima, sometimes with the qualifier *strict* when suitable.

---

For a real-valued function $f$ whose domain is a set $X$ of real numbers (usually an interval or union of intervals), a point $x_{0}$ of $X$ is often called:

- An *absolute minimum* of $f$ if $f(x_{0}) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$.
- A *relative minimum* or *local minimum* of $f$ if there exists a positive real number $r$ such that $f(x_{0}) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$ with $|x - x_{0}| < r$.

Sometimes one wants to avoid or forbid the possibility of "non-uniqueness" of minima, and calls $x_{0}$:

- A *strict absolute minimum* of $f$ if $f(x_{0}) < f(x)$ for all $x$ in $X \setminus \{x_{0}\}$ (i.e., for all $x \neq x_{0}$).
- A *strict local minimum* of $f$ if there exists a positive real number $r$ such that $f(x_{0}) < f(x)$ for all $x$ in $X \setminus\{x_{0}\}$ with $|x - x_{0}| < r$.

The "absolute" terms make sense as-is for real-valued functions on an arbitrary set; the "local" terms extend almost without modification to real-valued functions on a topological space, where there is a notion of "neighborhoods."

Comment: I think this answer slightly misses the point of the question as the fact that the minimum is reached multiple times is part of the concept the OP is asking a name for. Based on your answer, "recurrent non-absolute minimum" or "recurrent absolute minimum" seem appropriate terms.

Comment: @nicomezi You may be right, based on the question title. <> In any case, your _recurrent_ suggestion is reasonable. If OP clarifies their intent, I'll either delete this or make it community wiki, in which case please feel free to add your insight!

Comment: @andrew-d-hwang I added what I believe is the intent, please respond if you need more context.

Comment: Thank you, that does clarify! Like nicomezi, I haven't heard of a standard term for this, other than as described in this answer, but agree that _recurrent_ would provide useful emphasis if it's important that (local or absolute) minima of the same critical value are achieved multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a name for that. But you could call them "periodic minimals" or "frequent minimals" since they apear periodically (or frequently). In the case  of $f(x)=sin()+sin(.5)$, the "periodic minimal" has the form $f^{-1}(-1.76) + k4\pi$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand, it is not true when you say that $f(x) \approx -.369$ is also a periodic minimal, in the sense that $f(f^{-1}(-.369) + k4\pi) \leq f(x)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ **and for any**  $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R} \, : \, x = f^{-1}(-1.76) + k4\pi\}$, ¿what about the green dot?

I guess you mean $f^{-1}(-.369) + k4\pi$ has zero derivative in those points, in that case you can define it as "frequent local minimum" or "periodic local minimum" and the definition is the same idea as the first paragraph.

[image]